# Grails Spring Security LDAP Plugin: Use LDAP for auth but only allow users stored in the database to login

Tags: security, spring, plugins, grails, ldap

I have a table of usernames that map to LDAP usernames. What I want to do is to have a list of users or just usernames in a database and only allow users in the list to be authenticated against the LDAP server. I want to be able to authenticate against an LDAP server but only allow those usernames that are in the database and enabled to be able to login. I have been able to successfully setup the spring security core and LDAP so that users can login. How do I authenticate only users that are enabled in the database to login to the grails app using spring security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to subclass Spring Security's [LdapAuthenticationProvider](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/ldap/LdapAuthenticationProvider.html). Override the authenticate method that it returns `null` if a requested login is not valid for ldap auth (aka not in your table).

The next step is add your new custom AuthenticationProvider class to the providerlist as described in [Spring Security Core plugin docs](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/10%20Authentication%20Providers.html).